# View Not Being Presented from NavbarItem

Tags: swiftui

This should display the `Text` view, but in practice when tapped nothing happens:

```
struct NavTest: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List {
                Text("List Item in Navigation View")
            }
                .navigationBarTitle(Text("Troubled Code"))
                .navigationBarItems(trailing: NavigationButton(destination: Text("Inaccessible")) {
                    Image(systemName: "slider.horizontal.3")
                })
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT: Yes I'm aware that it works with `PresentationButton` but for some indiscernible reason, (I think something to do with Property Wrappers and Core Data) that crashes my app 100% of the time. So any other ways of presenting Views from buttons would also be appreciated

Comment: Which version of Xcode do you use ? In beta 3 NavigationButton is deprecated use NavigationLink instead

Comment: Oh wow - had no idea, I'll give that a try